# ReactJS: Importing css into one file changes styling of whole app

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using a dependency called "antd". It contains a css file (antd/dist/antd.css) which I import in one file.

I only want the styling in the file where I imported it. However, it also changes the styling of the header! How can I make it so only Content.js uses this styling?

I recreated my issue in the following codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-dream-5e6dp

Additionally, here is the code also.

**Index**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

**App**

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Content from "./Content";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Header**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Header() {
  return <div>This is the header, this should not be in antd styling</div>;
}
```

**Content**

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Table, Button, Popconfirm, Row, Col, Icon, Upload } from "antd";

export default function ExcelPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      This should be in antd styling.
      <Button>
        <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872285/react-css-how-to-apply-css-to-specific-pages-only

Comment: @Reactord This makes sense! Unfortunately I only see a solution for a selfmade css file. Could you make a suggestion on how to make it work with antd.css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you work with a recently new create-react-app you should have access to css-modules. This feature allows you to bundle a CSS file to the JSX only where you imported it.
Read about it in the documentation for CSS-modules and react (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/). In the end it should just work out by naming your file "XXX.module.css". So much for the specifity.

You can also do that with SCSS files. Those (idk if that is rather a CSS-feature) allow you to import other CSS/SCSS files on top. With that and css/scss modules it should be very possible to contain your styles.

Comment: Does this mean I have to grab the css file from the dependency from antd and rename it? Or is there a way to keep it in the dependency (for future updates for example)?

Comment: I thought it would be possible to make a CSS module name "ExcelPage.module.css".
In this CSS you can do @import "antd/dist/antd.css"
Then the styles should be imported under a specialized tag. If not you can still specifically override the styles.
I dont know antd but with Material UI it would be: .Mui-error {...// STYLES...} to override the class specific to the component I imported that CSS-module for. 
Try it out, I think you can make it work with a bit of trial and error.