# What's the CSS behavior in React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**Note:**
No need to understand my code, just focus on the 3 components files **Palette.js**, **Palette.css** and **footer.js**

Firstly I created my footer component in **Palette.js** and write CSS for its styling in **Palette.css**, which is linked to only **Palette.js**. in order to use the footer in different files, I created a new footer component in a separate file[**footer.js**] but forget to import styles from **Palette.css** which are used to style my footer, I removed my whole footer component from **Palette.js** and import my footer component from **footer.js** in **Palette.js**
My footer component looks like [**footer.js** without any stylesheet]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
function Footer(props){
     const { creater, emoji, paletteName} = props;
     return (
          <footer>     
               <h2 className="palette-creater">Palette Created by : {creater}</h2>
               <div className="palette-identity">
                    <span className="palette-emoji">
                         {emoji}
                    </span>
                    <span className="palette-name">
                         {paletteName}
                    </span>
               </div>
               <h3 className="palette-copyright">All rights reserved @ Colors.io 2021</h3>             
          </footer>
     )
}
export default Footer;
```

My **Palette.js** looks like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ColorBox from './ColorBox';
import NavBar from './NavBar';    
import Footer from './footer' ;// imported my footer
import './Palette.css';
//styles for footer component in footer.js are still in this file

export default class Palette extends Component{
 render(){
    return (
      <Footer creater={creater} emoji={emoji} paletteName={paletteName} />
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see my **footer.js** has no styles and my **Palette.js** has a CSS file **palette.css** which has styles for my footer. Also, the styles for my footer in the **Palette.css** looks like

```
footer{
     background-color: #ced0d1;
     font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
     padding: 5px;
     text-align: center
}

.palette-creater{
     
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     margin: 0;
     font-weight: 500;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     
}

.palette-identity{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;

}

.palette-name{
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     font-weight: 400;
}
.palette-emoji{
     display: block;
     font-size: 1rem;
}

.palette-copyright{
     margin:0;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

How my styles are applying to the footer component from **Palette.css**, which is not even linked with the **footer.js**, and also no matter wherever I import my footer component from **footer.js** and used it, it's always applying styles from **Palette.css**. My application is pretty large, I cannot post all the code.

**Example**
just think of that I make a new file app.css and linked it with only  App.js and writes all the styles of the application in app.css, then all the components take styles from here.

Comment: CSS is not scoped. Any CSS that any of your components imports will end up being added globally in your HTML page and will affect any element with a matching class name.

Comment: Ohh Thanks....It just cleared my whole confusion..I totally agreed with your fact. Thank you soo much!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll be able to find your answer here: [React CSS - how to apply CSS to specific pages only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872285/react-css-how-to-apply-css-to-specific-pages-only)

The key element from the above link is that "Create React App bundles all your css files into one so all the styles will be available everywhere in you app (on every rendered component). Be aware that CRA is a Single-Page Application (SPA) so you can't think in "pages" but rather in "rendered component" in the DOM."